# What's the difference between `.map(f)` and `.map(|x| f(x))`?

Tags: rust, iterator, dereference, type-coercion

When doing [rustlings `standard_library_types/iterators2.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/standard_library_types/iterators2.rs), I started wondering how [`std::iter::Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) calls its argument closure/function. More specifically, suppose I have a function

```rust
// "hello" -> "Hello"
pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = input.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(first) => String::from(first.to_ascii_uppercase()) + c.as_str(),
    }
}
```

Now I want to use it in

```rust
// Apply the `capitalize_first` function to a slice of string slices.
// Return a vector of strings.
// ["hello", "world"] -> ["Hello", "World"]
pub fn capitalize_words_vector(words: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    words.into_iter().map(capitalize_first).collect()
}
```

which doesn't compile

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> exercises/standard_library_types/iterators2.rs:24:27
   |
11 | pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
   | ---------------------------------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> _`
...
24 |     words.into_iter().map(capitalize_first).collect()
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(&&str) -> _`

error[E0599]: the method `collect` exists for struct `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> exercises/standard_library_types/iterators2.rs:24:45
   |
24 |       words.into_iter().map(capitalize_first).collect()
   |                                               ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first} as FnOnce<(&&str,)>>::Output = _`
           which is required by `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>: Iterator`
           `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}: FnMut<(&&str,)>`
           which is required by `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>: Iterator`
           `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> String {capitalize_first}>: Iterator`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0599, E0631.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

However, it works fine after I changed `.map(capitalize_first)` to `.map(|x| capitalize_first(x))`. Apparently, Rust borrows (not sure mutable or immutable) each item before passing it to the argument closure/function of `map`, which makes sense because we typically don't want to consume the objects being iterated over.

What I cannot understand is why Rust doesn't borrow the arguments to `|x| capitalize_first(x)`. I hypothesize that the closure `|x| capitalize_first(x)` still got `&&str`, and then the [auto-dereferencing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) kicked in and dereferenced it to `&str`, but that doesn't explain why it didn't kick in when I'm using the function `capitalize_first`. What's the difference between `.map(|x| capitalize_first(x))` and `.map(capitalize_first)`? Is dynamic dispatch happening here, given that the argument to `map` is a trait object?

**Note:** this question is not a duplicate to [Using a function with iter().map() - as a named function vs as a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005135/using-a-function-with-iter-map-as-a-named-function-vs-as-a-closure) because I am asking *why*, whereas the other post asked *how*. Regarding the accepted answer to that question, I would appreciate it if someone could explain why we need `AsRef` while Rust already has [auto-dereferencing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules).

Comment: Related Q&A: [What is the difference between `filter(func)` and `filter(|x| func(x))`?](/q/73823725/2189130) but the problem there was a difference between *late-bound* and *early-bound* lifetimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Why can I call `capitalize_first` with a `&&str` argument?*

The linked Q&A for [auto-dereferencing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) is specifically for how `self` is resolved when using the `a.b()` syntax. The rules for arguments in general skip the auto-reference step and just rely on [*deref coercions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion). Since `&&str` implements `Deref<Target = &str>` (and indeed *all* references implement `Deref`), this `&&str` -> `&str` transformation happens transparently.

*Why doesn't it work for `.map(f)` then?*

Plain and simply, `map()` is expecting something that implements `Fn(&&str) -> T` and `capitalize_first` does not. A `Fn(&str)` is not transparently transformed into a `Fn(&&str)`, it requires a transformation step like the one introduced by the closure (albeit transparently).

Comment: *(and indeed all references implement Deref)* I wish you could expand on that: does `&T` always implement `Deref<Target = T>`, so that I can always pass a `&T` to `f(x: T)`? The document doesn't seem to mention this, so I'd better ask for some clarification.

Comment: @nalzok no, deref coercion only work on `&T` to `&U` transformations; both have to be references. Its designed for cases like `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]` or `&String` to `&str` or `&Box<T>` to `&T`.

Comment: I see, but how does `&&str` -> `&str` fit into that picture? In general, so we have `&…&&T` -> `&…&T`?

Answer (score 1):

@kmdreko is correct that the issue is with deref coercion. Keep in mind that `&[T]` implements `IntoIterator` with `Self::Item` being `&T`. Thus, if `x : &[T]`, then `x.into_iter()` will implement the `Iterator` with `Self::Item` being `&T`.

In your case, `words.into_iter()` is an `Iterator` with `Self::Item` being `&&str`.

The `map` method expects a function with domain `Self::Item`. `words.into_iter().map(f)` expects `f` to be a function with input of type `&&str`.

This creates a problem because `capitalize_first` takes as its input a `&str`, not a `&&str`. Thus, `words.into_iter().map(capitalize_first)` fails to type check.

However, when we look at `words.into_iter().map(|x| capitalize_first(x))`, something magical happens. The closure `|x| capitalize_first(x)` gets magically coerced to `|x| capitalize_first(*x)`. This then type-checks.

Comment: *Keep in mind that `&[T]` implements `IntoIterator` with `Self::Item` being `&T`.* Could you point me to where it's documented?

Comment: @nalzok https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-IntoIterator Search for "impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T]"